requests module dependency warning
Warning: venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:109: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (2.2.1) or chardet (2.3.0)/charset_normalizer (3.3.2) doesn't match a supported version!
Environment: Docker, Ubuntu. Building from Dockerfile.
Relevant Dockerfile lines:
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip python3-venv libcairo2-dev pkg-config python3-dev tesseract-ocr ffmpeg poppler-utils libportaudio2 swig libpulse-dev libpango1.0-dev
RUN apt-get clean

# Use the virtual environment
RUN python3 -m venv /usr/src/app/venv

# Install dependencies from requirements.txt
RUN /usr/src/app/venv/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade --force-reinstall -r /usr/src/app/requirements.txt

Requirements:
wheel

# -- Problematic section --
requests
urllib3>=2.1.0
charset_normalizer
# -------------------------

Other requirements omitted for brevity.
The warning is shown regardless of whether the requests module is used.
Reading online, and other StackOverflow threads, the consensus is that updating the requests library solves the problem, but I am using the latest version (2.31.0) and the warning is still there.
Originally, this was my pip install line in the Dockerfile:
RUN /usr/src/app/venv/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir -r /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
I added the --upgrade and --force-reinstall flags to no avail.
It could be an issue with a library I have omitted, but there are 95 in total and many are likely unrelated.

Do you have the same problem in a non-Docker virtual environment?  If not, you might run pip freeze > requirements.txt to contain a more requirements lock file that lists a consistent set of exact package versions that should work.

Upgrading pip before installing requirements solved the issue:
RUN /usr/src/app/venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
RUN /usr/src/app/venv/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade --force-reinstall -r /usr/src/app/requirements.txt```

